# How to solve this with Akka actors?

Tags: akka, reactive-programming

didn't know how to name this thread but will try to explain the problem in few lines.

I have a command which need to calculate price for desired date range. To calculate it system needs to fetch the price for every day individually (DB, config, cache, it doesn't matter from where).

My suggestion was to have one PriceRangeActor which will have a pool of DailyPriceActors and will send them commands like CalculateDailyPrice.

But how to assemble all that data in PriceRanceActor?

1.
Having some big map with complex keys just smells a lot. How to determine then if the range is completely calculated? Is there any easier way of doing this?

2.
Create new PriceRangeActor for every command and use ask pattern to query the list of DailyPriceActors?

Comment: I'd go for a second option. Future composition is much easier than explicit message exchange in this case.

Comment: Why don't you create a chain of Actors, each will have daily price, and then you pass your message along the chain, with each actor adding to the result, and with the last one - return back to sender :-) Probably depends on how large the range is.

Comment: Thx guys. @kukido but that way I'll lose the possibility to do the calculations in parallel.

Comment: It looks similar to the problem solved with the [cameo pattern](https://github.com/jamie-allen/effective_akka/blob/e17021b1e371e9f1fe7d18ca48cde7c4a68fa196/src/main/scala/org/jamieallen/effectiveakka/pattern/cameo/Cameo.scala) in the book effective akka. Basically call N services and aggregate results when they are all ready. I think it's worth to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you aren't utilizing any message passing/queuing I suggest Futures rather than Actors as your concurrency abstraction mechanism.  This [blog entry](https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/actors_vs_futures.html) makes a very compelling argument that Actors are for state and Futures are for computation.

With either Futures or Actor `?` (which is a Future) you can use [`Future.sequence`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$) to bundle together all of the separate querying Futures into a single Future that only completes once all the sub-queries are complete.

**USING FUTURES** (recommended)

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Foo extends App {

  type Date = Int
  type Prices = Seq[Float]
  type PriceMap = Map[Date, Prices]

  //expensive query function
  def fetchPrices(date : Date) : Prices = ???

  //the Dates to query Prices for
  val datesToQuery : Seq[Date] = ???

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._

  def concurrentQuery(date : Date) : Future[Prices] = Future {fetchPrices(date)}      

  //launches a Future per date query, D Dates => D Futures
  //Future.sequence converts the D Futures into 1 Future
  val dates2PricesFuture : Future[PriceMap] = 
    Future.sequence(datesToQuery map concurrentQuery)
          .map(datesToQuery zip _)  
          .map(_.toMap)      

  dates2PricesFuture onSuccess { case priceMap : PriceMap =>
    //process the price data which is now completely available
  }

}//end object Foo
```

**USING ACTORS**

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout

object Foo extends App {          
  type Date = Int
  type Prices = Seq[Float]
  type PriceMap = Map[Date, Prices]

  def fetchPrices(date : Date) : Prices = ???

  val datesToQuery : Seq[Date] = ???

  class QueryActor() extends Actor {
    def receive = { case date : Date => sender ! fetchPrices(date) }
  }

  implicit val as = ActorSystem()
  implicit val queryTimeout = Timeout(1000)

  import as.dispatcher

  def concurrentQuery(date : Date) : Future[Prices] =    
    ask(as actorOf Props[QueryActor],date).mapTo[Prices]

  val dates2PricesFuture : Future[PriceMap] = 
        Future.sequence(datesToQuery map concurrentQuery)
              .map(datesToQuery zip _)  
              .map(_.toMap)

  dates2PricesFuture onSuccess ... //same as first example

}//end object Foo
```